# Casting and Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

Consider this simple code:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A[] a, a1;
        B[] b;
        a = new A[10];
        a1 = a;
        b = new B[20];
        a = b; // 1
        b = (B[]) a; // 2
        b = (B[]) a1; // 3
    }
}
```

Look closely at lines which I commented 1,2 and 3. The line 1 will be allowed during compilation, since assignment is done from a subclass reference to a superclass reference.

The cast in line 2 is needed because a superclass reference is assigned to a subclass reference variable. And this works at runtime because the object referenced to by a is actually of an array of B (line 1).

Now, here's where lies my confusion: line 3 will throw a java.lang.ClassCastException. Now, this means that during runtime, the program realizes that the actual object is not an array of B but is an array of A.

This is exactly what I don't understand. Doesn't B extends A? So it satisfies the condition B IS-A A, correct? And therefore, shouldn't line 3 not throw any exception during run time?

Comment: Please take the time to format the code you provide. It's *really, really* hard to read at the moment, with no indentation and multiple statements on one line. Please bear in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers - put the time in to make your question genuinely high quality.

Comment: "So it satisfies the condition B IS-A A, correct?" Correct. But what you would need is "A IS-A B" - but you do not have that. I guess the confusion is from here: `a1 = a;  a = b; // 1` - by changing the reference `a` you are **not** changing `a1`. It still is pointing to the same `A[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a1` is an array of `A` elements. Since `B` extends `A`, all instances of `B` are also instances of `A`, but not all instances of `A` are instances of `B`. You could define a class `C` that also extends `A` and assign instances of that class to the `a1` array. Such instances are not instances of `B`.

Therefore you can't cast an array of `A` elements to an array of `B` elements.

Comment: But the code compiles fine. It throws an exception during runtime. However, let's say I made an array like this :-`TestClass c[] = new TestClass[20]`. Now when I try `b = (B[]) c`, it gives doesn't compile saying **incompatible types**. Why are there different behaviors ?

Comment: @Shashwat You can assign a B[] instance to an A[] variable (just like you can assign a B instance to an A variable). Therefore casting an A[] variable to B[] (or an A variable to B) may succeed in runtime it the runtime types match. However, a TestClass[]  can never be cast to B[], since TestClass is not a sub-class of B and B is not a sub-class of TestClass. That's why the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Although you cannot do `b = (B[]) a1;`,   `b` and `a1` are compatible types and that is all the compiler looks for, so it compiles correctly, though it is actually impossible to assign `b` equal to `a1`. Please correct me If I'm wrong,.

Comment: @Shashwat `b = (B[]) a1;` could succeed in runtime if prior to this line you have a line that assigns an instance of `B[]` to `a1` (for example `a1 = new B[10];`). The compiler doesn't analyze the runtime type of `a1`. It only analyzes its compile time type to determine whether the cast could succeed in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot, that arrays are classes by themselves, and they have their own cast and assignment rules.

Consider this:

```
    A[] aa = new A[0];
    B[] bb = new B[0];

    System.out.println(aa.getClass());
    System.out.println(bb.getClass());

    System.out.println(aa.getClass().isAssignableFrom(bb.getClass()));
    System.out.println(bb.getClass().isAssignableFrom(aa.getClass()));
```

Output:

```
class [Lstuff.small.Try47$A;
class [Lstuff.small.Try47$B;
true
false
```

Thus, an A[] variable can indeed be assigned a B[], but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying "B IS-A A" and that is why 
  i) There is no issue when you put a = b; 
  ii) There is no issue at compile time for statement #3

But You can not say "A IS-A B", thus the run time exception.